# convert java project in a .exe file using Fedora

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project in Eclipse and I want to make it a .exe file. I've managed to do it in Windows but I want to make it work also in Fedora/Ubuntu. Does anyone know any solution?

Comment: If its pure `Java project` then make `jar` file it would work everywhere where `Java` installed.

Comment: So there's no chance to make it .exe, only jar?

Comment: You can use [exe4J](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files) to wrap executable java archives into a native executable for either PC or linux. It's commercial software though.

Comment: You can check @Mena suggest a commercial tool I dont think any freeware tool support this and in Linux you can run `exe` by `WINE`

Comment: You could also have a simple batch script for PC executing your java archive, but that would likely require having a (compatible) JRE installed in a default location in the target system.

Comment: @spoke .exe is a windows native executable, they can't be used on other platforms. I very much doubt there's much use for those who use linux, to create a file they can not run without an intermediary tool.
That being said: a .jar file should do all the tasks you probably need. Yes, the client will need to have a JRE installed, but that remains so with an exe as well. Yes, the environment settings need to be set, but I don't see this as being too much a problem.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Raedwald it's a task that my boss gave me